# replace string every 3 x characters appear in PHP

Tags: php

Is there a php function that is able to replace when a character appear x time?

example

```
$string="a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j,k,l";
```

every 3 commas will append "\n\r"

```
a,b,c,
d,e,f,
g,h,i,
j,k,l
```

I have written this.

```
function addBreaks($string,$char,$count) {  
    $ii = 0;
    for ( $i = 0; $i < strlen($string); $i++){  
        if ($string[$i] == $char){
            $ii++;      
            }
        if ($ii == $char){      
            $ii = 0;

            }
        $string = $string[$i]+"\n\r"+$string[$i+1]; 
        }
        return $string;
    }
```

Comment: and... what have you tried so far?

Comment: **Try writing something yourself** and then if it doesn't work, **show us specifically what you did** so we can help you along. You start it, we help. We don't write it for you.  Show us the actual code that you've tried and then we can help you from there.  Chances are you'll get pretty close to the answer if you just try it yourself first.

Comment: A function for **splitting** a string? Did you try googling for "PHP split string"?

Comment: It can be achieved in so many ways. Either simply looping it and splitting it, or `preg_replace` should do the job.

Comment: Please don't reduce my reputation.. I did try, what I am asking for is whether there is a build in function in PHP

Comment: You could try `preg_split` but I'm not sure how useful it will be in this case

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this could work (very rough):

```
function addLineBreaks( $str, $n = ',', $x = 3 ) {
    $sArr = str_split( $str );
    $output = '';
    $occ = 0;
    foreach( $sArr as $k=>$v ) {
        $output .= $v;          
        if( $v == $n ) {
            $occ++;
            if( $occ%$x == 0 ) $output .= "\r\n";           
        }
    }

    return $output;
}
```

Use it like:

```
header("Content-Type:text/plain");
echo addLineBreaks( "a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j,k,l" );
// outputs:
//a,b,c,
//d,e,f,
//g,h,i,
//j,k,l
```

Answer (score 2):

you could use [chunk_split()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.chunk-split.php):

```
echo chunk_split($string, 6, '<br />'); //6 because after every third comma so count characters
```

this seems to do with any number of letters::

```
$string = "a,b,c,d,easda,f,g,hasd,i,j,k,l";

function split_me($str, $delim, $pos) {
    return implode($delim."<br />", array_map(function($arr) use ($delim) {
          return implode($delim, $arr);
    }, array_chunk(explode($delim, $str), $pos)));
}
echo split_me($string,",", 3);
```

Comment: Keep in mind this won't work if there are a variable amount of  letters between commas, ex: a,bcd,efghijk - but I like this.

Answer (score 2):

This will work no matter how many letters there are between commas (it adds a break after every $count commas it finds):

```
function addLineBreaks($string,$char,$count) {
    return preg_replace("/(?:[^$char]+$char){{$count}}/","\\0<br />",$string);
}
```

Example usage:

```
echo addLineBreaks("a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j,k,l",",",3);
```

Comment: nice, i wish i could do such regex.. they simply dont get into my head .. :)